# Pandas Dataframe cutting off extra digits from excel import

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading in an excel sheet into the dataframe, which has worked great. However, one of the columns in the excel sheet has an ID number which is forced to 5 forward digits. Thus, rather than 32, the excel sheet has 00032 and for 500 it would be 00500. When I read this file into pandas however it converts these numbers to it's base value, thus 00500 becomes 500 in the dataframe. However, as I am trying to match the file names which use the 5 digit index value to the ID number this is actually causing an issue. I would just use a list system but I need pandas to easily access multiple columns of data when iterating through the rows. Here is the gist:

```
downloads = r'C:\Users\...'
filelist = os.listdir(downloads)
SDC = []
for file in filelist:
    if file.startswith('sdc'):
        SDC.append(file[3:8])
print SDC
if SDC == []:
    print "There are no downloaded files to grab at this time."

dir = r'C:\...'
os.chdir(dir)
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['SDC ID'] in SDC:
        dir = r'C:\bleh\Temporary Folder' + row['Theme']
        if not os.path.exists(dir):
             os.makedirs(dir)
```

How do I force the original value in pandas to quickly iterate and check values against the list?

Comment: The column contains integers, so `00500` is just how excel displays the integer

Comment: I get that, however i need the import to force the extra digits to be kept. I dont see a way to force a column input as string when importing.

Comment: You are comparing an integer to a string. This will never work regardless of the formatting. Pick one type and do the comparison in that type.

Comment: As far as I remember, the conversion is not at pandas level but at xlrd or openpyxl level. They convert strings to numbers when possible so even if you pass converters to the read_excel function, you cannot get back the strings. I'll try to find the issue raised in github.

Comment: @MadPhysicist The OP says the Excel cell contains `00032` (which is a string) but pandas converts that to `32` which is an integer. Here are two issues: [1](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/11331), [2](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/8212)

Comment: @ayhan. The excel cell may be formatted to represent `32` as `00032`. If it contains a string, it should be something like `'00032`.

Comment: @ayhan. I rescind my previous comment. It is not clear whether you are correct or not, but either way the question is unclear. Knowing what is in the actual dataframe is all-important here. Where it came from is irrelevant, and OP doesn't even bother to show how the dataframe is loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `if row['SDC ID'] in SDC:` checks if an integer exists in a list of strings. There are two simple solutions that I can see:

1. Compare as strings. Format your integer into a string and keep the test mostly as-is. Something like `if '{:05d}'.format(row['SDC ID']) in SDC:` should do it. It will format your integer to a zero padded five-digit number.
2. Compare as integers. You can convert the numbers from the file names directly into integers as you find them since you don't appear to be using their string properties anywhere. Change the line `SDC.append(file[3:8])` to `SDC.append(int(file[3:8]))`.

Given the information shown, I would prefer the second option, but not by much and for no good reason beyond aesthetics.

Comment: I tried the second method earlier today, as i thought that was the easy answer. However, this method still kept the 0s for some reason thus a direct compare with the if statements resulted in failed responses. I'll try your first suggestion now.

Comment: @WolVes. You need to provide a small sample of your `df` variable and the types of the columns in your question.

Comment: Sorry, will do so in the future. Thanks for your help Mad Physicist!

Comment: @WolVes. Could you do it now? It might attract a better solution in the future. I am also curious to see what the real issue is.